# ExtJS 5 application + Django rest framework CORS error when changing URL of store

Tags: django, extjs, cors, django-rest-framework, django-cors-headers

I am developing a ExtJS application that uses a Django-rest-framework service. I am using CORS headers to allow fetching the data from the service (https://github.com/OttoYiu/django-cors-headers).

What happens is that at a point in time I want to change the URL from the store. And when I do that I get the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://10.98.0.241:8000/reacsearch/as?_dc=1418831884352&page=1&start=0&limit=25. The request was redirected to 'http://10.98.0.241:8000/reacsearch/as/?_dc=1418831884352&page=1&start=0&limit=25', which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight.
```

In the settings.oy I define the following properties for the CORS

```
CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = (
        'GET',
        'OPTIONS'
    )

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

This works fine when I use URLs to list all the elements in my database, however when I change the store for another URL I get the error above. Also the link works fine in the browser.

The store url change is made this way:

```
var store = Ext.getStore(storeName);
store.getProxy().setUrl(newURL);
store.load();
```

The difference between the views, is that the two that work on the application are viewsets, while the other is just a generic list

```
class Example1viewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoing that allows metabolites to be viewed.
    """
    queryset = examples1.objects.all()
    serializer_class = Example1Serializer

class Example1SearchList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = Example1Serializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Example.objects.all()

        if 'attr' in self.kwargs:
            queryset = queryset.filter(Q(attribute1__contains=self.kwargs['attr']) | Q(attribute2__contains=self.kwargs['abbr']))

        return queryset
```

Like I mentioned both examples work fine in the browser (even accessing through other computers in the network), however in the application when changing the URL of the store I get the CORS error. Does anyone has any idea why this is happening?

Thank you.

**Edit:**

Just for clarification, the problem is not in changing the url of the store. As I tried to set those urls as defaults, but they are not working when accessing from the application.

My urls.py file:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'example', views.Example1ViewSet)

# Wire up our API using automatic URL routing.
# Additionally, we include login URLs for the browsable API.
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^reacsearch/(?P<attr>.+)/$', Example1SearchList.as_view()),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
```

Can it be that the problem is related with the fact that I am not adding the search list to the router?

**Edit2**

Problem solved since I was trying to fetch data from a different domain. I changed the type of store to jsonp in Extjs, and I also allowed my rest service to render data as jsonp.

Just a reminder if anyone comes accross this same problem, it is necessary to add ?format=jsonp to the store url:

```
http://my/url/?format=jsonp
```

Comment: Are you sure your CORS headers are being included in the response? I'd check in your developer tools just to make sure.

Comment: I think the problem comes from the store load in ExtJS now. I am trying to figure out a way to use JSONP store, since I want to load the data from a different domain that my application will live on. Still getting some empty stores, but if I manage to do this I will update. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since it looks like an alternate solution was found, I'll explain what the issue appeared to be as well as why the alternative works.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load `first url`. The request was redirected to '`second url`', which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight.

The issue here is that you are telling Django to enforce the trailing slash, which makes it automatically redirect urls without a trailing slash to urls with a trailing slash, assuming that one exists. This is why, as stated in the error, the request was redirected to the second url, which you can tell has the missing trailing slash. This is controlled by [the `APPEND_SLASH` Django setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#append-slash) which is `True` by default.

The problem is that when CORS is doing a preflight request, which is what allows it to determine if the request can be made, there must be a valid response *at the requested URL*. Because you are redirecting the request, the preflight request fails and you're stuck without your information.

You can fix this by adding the trailing slash in your code. There appear to be a few [solutions for doing this with ext](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?139754-How-To-Get-Ext.data.RestProxy-To-Use-Trailing-Slashes), but I personally can't recommend a specific one. You can also manually set the url to use the trailing slash, which sounds like what you were doing previously.

**Or you can use JSONP...**

You've found the alternative solution, which is to use JSONP to make the request instead of relying on CORS. This gets around the preflight issue and works in all major browsers, but there are some drawbacks to consider. You can find more [information on CORS vs JSONP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12296910/359284) by looking around.

You're going to need CORS if you want to push any changes to your API, as JSONP only supports `GET` requests. There are other advantages, such as the ability to abort requests, that also comes with CORS.

Comment: Very nice explanation thanks. For this particular case GET operations will be enough, but on a later stage I might want to use other things, so this reply was particularly useful.